# Stream & Azure API Vision

Tags: c#, azure, stream

I'm trying to use Azure API Vision to read text on image and it works perfecly.
But after added a little code to detect if my image was black (no text) I got an error from Azure API: "**Bad Request**".
When I don't want to use my little function to detect black, it works again.

I imagine that is because my stream is converted in an other object but I don't know what object...

This is my code:

```
var streamImage = this.printScreenService.CaptureRegionToStream(screenRegion);
var isBlack = await this.IsBlack(streamImage);

if (isBlack)
{
    return new OcrModel
    {
        IsBlack = true,
        Texts = new[] { "" }
    };
} 

var localFileOcrResult = await this.client.RecognizePrintedTextInStreamAsync(true, streamImage, OcrLanguages.Fr);

-----

private bool IsBlack(Stream stream)
{
    var image = new Bitmap(Image.FromStream(stream));

    for (var h = 0; h < image.Height; h++)
    {
        for (var w = 0; w < image.Width; w++)
        {
            var color = image.GetPixel(w, h);
            if ((color.R != color.G || color.G != color.B || color.R != color.B) && color.A != 0)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

I tried to use CopyToAsync stream but it not works.

Thanks for your help

Comment: try to save image to your local hard disk and check if you can open it (through image viewer / windows explorer / paint)

Comment: @ThiagoCustodio After "IsBlack" process? Or before?

Comment: inside IsBlack method. Just to make sure it's not corrupted

Comment: @ThiagoCustodio I put "image.Save("test.bmp");" and I can open it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After calling you IsBlack method, you should return the stream to position 0:

```
var streamImage = this.printScreenService.CaptureRegionToStream(screenRegion);
var isBlack = await this.IsBlack(streamImage);

if (isBlack)
{
    return new OcrModel
    {
        IsBlack = true,
        Texts = new[] { "" }
    };
} 
streamImage.Position = 0; //this line
var localFileOcrResult = await this.client.RecognizePrintedTextInStreamAsync(true, streamImage, OcrLanguages.Fr);
```

Comment: Ahaha simply... !
Any explanations?

Comment: It's because you're using the same stream. After you read, it requires this rewind

Comment: Thank you ! Thiago